# 3 query dependents mongo and nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb

tengo un método con tres consultas a bases de datos pero una depende del resultado de la otra,y no puedo mantener la secuencia y los resultados, ¿alguna ayuda? Gracias

```
    exports.buscarSupervisoresTotales = (req, res) => {

        var salidaprimera = []
        var salidasegunda = []
        var salidaFinal = []



        async function foo() {
            try {
                let resultado = await ListarSupervisoresTotales();
                let nuevoResultado = await ListarSupervisoresTotales2proceso();
                let resultadoFinal = await ListarSupervisoresTotales3proceso();

                return res.status(200).json({ salidasegunda })
            }
        }
```

Primer método, acá hago una consulta a la base de datos y se lo pusheo a  salidaprimera:

```
       async function ListarSupervisoresTotales() {
            try {

                let listado1 = await Workers.aggregate([{
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "Manager_id": "$Manager_id"
                        }
                    }
                }], (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
                    if (!err) {
                        salidaprimera.push(registrosEncontrados)

                        return (registrosEncontrados)

                    }
                }
                )
            }
```

Segundo método que depende del resultado del anterior, toma lo que está en salidaprimera y hace un query con esos valores y lo pushea a salida segunda...

```
       async function ListarSupervisoresTotales2proceso(resultado) {
            try {
                await

                    salidaprimera.reduce((acumulador, item) => {

                        let valor = buscar(item)

                        return valor


                    }), {}

            }

        }
```

Tercer método que depende del resultado del segundo método, acá tomo lo que esta en salidasegunda y realizo otra consulta y pusheo ese resultado a salidafinal

```
       async function ListarSupervisoresTotales3proceso() {
            try {
                 await

                     //reduce 
                     salidasegunda.reduce((acumulador, item2) => { }), {}
                 Evaluations.find({ '_id': item2._id }, (err, registrosEncontrados2) => {
                     salidasegunda.reduce((acumulador, item2) => {
                         item2 !== 'undefined' ? salidaFinal.push(item2) : console.log('nada')
                     }, {}
                     )
                 })
            }

        }
```

Cada método llena un arreglo porque no espera el resultado del mismo, no me hace lo que quiero, ¿tendrán una estructura o algo para guiarme? De antemano gracias

La variables que están declaradas al principio intenté utilizarlas pero el resultado no llega para ser tomado...

Comment: no me funciona, una yuda por favor...

Answer (score 0):

El problema que veo es que estas utilizando `await` pero no estas retornando una promesa, lo que espera `await` es una promesa valga la redundancia.

```js
var salida = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]   
var salidaprimera = []
var salidasegunda = []
var salidaFinal = []
async function foo(){
    await test1();
    await test2();
    await test3()
}
async function test1(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            salida.forEach((item)=>salidaprimera.push(item + 1))
            console.log(salidaprimera);
            resolve();
        },6000)
    });
}
async function test2(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
             salidaprimera.forEach((item)=>salidasegunda.push(item + 2))
             console.log(salidasegunda);
            resolve();
        },3000)
    });
}
async function test3(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(()=>{
             salidasegunda.forEach((item)=>salidaFinal.push(item + 3))
             console.log(salidaFinal);
            resolve();
        },1000)
    });
}
foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

No me funciona, el primer proceso lo hace bien pero en el segundo trae en blanco no se que estoy haciendo mal:

```
    async function foo() {
        let primerProceso = await ListarSupervisores();
        let segundoProceso = await ListarSupervisores2proceso(primerProceso);

    }
  async function ListarSupervisores() {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            Evaluations.aggregate([
                {
                    "$group": {
                        "_id": {
                            "domainLogin": "$domainLogin"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "domainLogin": "$_id.domainLogin",
                        "_id": 0
                    }
                }
            ], (err, registrosEncontrados) => {
                if (!err) {

                    resolve(registrosEncontrados)

                } else {
                    console.log('hola')
                    reject(err)
                }
            }
            )
        });






    }

    async function ListarSupervisores2proceso(valor) {

        return new Promise(resolve => {
            //  console.log(valor)
            valor.forEach((item) =>
                Workers.find({ 'DomainLogin': item.domainLogin }, (err, registrosEncontrados2) => {

                    segundaSalida.push(registrosEncontrados2)

                }))

                resolve()


        }


        )
    }
foo()
}
```

La segunda salida que depende de los resultados del primer proceso no trae los resultados…

Comment: Saludos, si esto no es una respuesta entonces debe ir en tu pregunta dando clic en editar para agregar lo que falte